# about Process control block in OS

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, process, operating-system

I recently reviewed OS concepts.
About Process control block, is there just a global ONE on one OS , or there is one PCB for each process?

Also, does this PCB only exist in RAM?

[I assume my question is target on Linux or Unix.]
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering one question at a time:

1. is there one PCB per process? YES. broadly speaking, Process control blocks are supposed to contain information(Scheduling, Memory, Time Accounting and others) of a process. This informed is used in various task related activities

PCB in linux is implemented as a structure known as task_struct(Please check the code at http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.12.6/include/linux/sched.h#L1023)

You can read a more about tasks and their internal @ http://linuxgazette.net/133/saha.html

2. Its basically more complicated than in memory or on disk. As far as I know, It is architecture dependent. Please check other answers : [Where is task_struct stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604632/where-is-task-struct-stored)
   I think this answers your question directly