# Is Page Table part of Process Control Block?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

Is page table part of **P**rocess **C**ontrol **B**lock or is it resides seperately.

If it resides seperately where does it resides?

Difference between Process Address Space and PCB?

Comment: Which operating system are you interested in?

Comment: @xmojmr I am learning yet. Most simplest will work (may be linux).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979011/about-process-control-block-in-os