# where is PCB stored in memory

Tags: linux, process, operating-system

I wanted to know where the PCB ( Process Control Block ) is stored in memory in Linux OS.. When the interrupt happens or scheduler is called, context switching code will replace the current process PCB and put it some where and load the new process PCB into memory.

I totally agree it is stored in RAM. But what is the name of such area in RAM.

What is the difference between address space and PCB . Are both same.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150746/61430

Comment: so it is stored on /proc file system which in turn is in RAM memory

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979011/about-process-control-block-in-os and Google query `site:stackoverflow.com linux process control block`

Comment: I have seen that, but it doesn't clearly specify where in RAM it stored. Consider for example malloc, we can say that it stores in heap

Comment: the above linked question states that the `task_struct`s are allocated using the [slab allocator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation). I would have to dive into the [linux source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux) to find out more. sorry

Comment: I guess it's kernel non-swap RAM.  That's where I would put it:)

Comment: @MartinJames: When I about to understand something someone left it with a smile.

Answer (score 0):

In a Linux OS, the Process Control Block (PCB) is stored in the kernel's memory space. The PCB contains essential information about a process, such as its state, program counter, stack pointer, CPU registers, scheduling information, and more. When an interrupt or scheduler is invoked, the context switching code will save the current process's PCB in memory and load the PCB of the new process into memory to continue its execution.

The PCB is part of the kernel's data structures and resides in a designated area of RAM called the kernel space or kernel address space. The kernel space is a protected area of memory that is only accessible by the kernel and is separate from the user space, where regular user-level processes reside.

Address space and PCB are not the same things. Address space refers to the range of memory addresses that a process can access. Each process has its own address space, which is a virtual address space mapped to physical memory by the operating system. PCB, on the other hand, is a data structure used by the operating system to manage and store information about processes. It contains information related to a specific process and is used by the kernel to manage and control the execution of processes.

Answer (score -1):

On most systems there is no process control block (I think it is safe to say that Linux has no such "PCB"). Process control block is a pedagogical concept used in some poorly written operating systems textbooks. What these books refer to is actually multiple data structures that can be stored in different locations.

The initialism PCB normally refers to the Process Context Block that is the area where the process context (ie registers) are stored.

Comment: Where are these location in RAM

Comment: Wherever the operating system wants to put them.

Comment: Is there are any special location or name as of Linux

Comment: So you're saying *Operating System Concepts* is a poorly written book? And what do you mean *a multiple data structures that can be stored in different locations*?

Comment: That book is, by far, the #1 source of confusion for students raised in this board. The operating system's process state is usually maintained in multiple data structures (that are linked) rather than a single block.